# Blanking screen @ 30 Second intervals for no apparent reason

Tags: power-management, monitor, lock-screen

My screen keeps blanking at 30 seconds if nothing is touched or moved. It seems to have started after a recent update.

I have tried changing screen-saver settings, xset values, and installing Caffeine. Caffeine, in spite of being active, appears to have no effect what so ever. Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas, as this is beginning to drive me potty?

JVO.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did this, but in case you didn't:

1. Open System Settings
2. Go to Brightness and Lock
3. Change "Turn screen off when inactive for:" from 30 seconds (if it is) to a more reasonable time
4. Do that too with "Lock screen after:"

Comment: Those were the first things I tried.